# Histogram overlay plot with lognormal distribution

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, scipy.stats

I want to check the fit of my data, which I suspect is lognormally distributed using a histogram and overlaying the lognormal PDF as a line. I estimate the lognormal parameters from the data and generate n=1000 data points (same number as the data). data_list is a list containing 1000 of my datapoints which are integers.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import lognorm

...
data = np.array(data_list)

plt.hist(data, bins=32, density=True, alpha=0.6, color='g', label='Data')

sigma, _, mu = lognorm.fit(np.log(data), floc=0)
x = np.linspace(min(data), max(data), 1000)
lognormal_data = lognorm.pdf(x, sigma, scale=np.exp(mu))


plt.plot(x, lognormal_data, 'r-', lw=2, label='Lognormal Distribution')
plt.xlabel('X-axis Label')
plt.ylabel('Y-axis Label')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Histogram Overlay with Lognormal Distribution')
plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

However, the resulting plot is this:
[image]

It seems like the initial parameters for the lognormal distribution ar off, as it does not coincide with the data. Furthermore, the curve looks more normal than lognormal. Does anybody see what i'm doing wrong here>

Comment: What is `data_list`?

Comment: I left it out for simplicity, but it's a list of 1000 of my datapoints, all integers.

Comment: Sorry but i load them from a .txt file, not sure how to add that

Comment: But to give you an idea, its data with ranging from 641 to 4909 with a mean of 1759

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no statistician, but if you suspect that `data` has a lognormal distribution, shouldn't you try to fit `data` instead of `np.log(data)`?

The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit) of the fit method states that it returns the following:

> Estimates for any shape parameters (if applicable), followed by those for location and scale.

The same documentation states that [`lognorm.pdf`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html#scipy.stats.lognorm) has the following signature: `pdf(x, s, loc=0, scale=1)`.

I would therefore try the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import lognorm

data = np.random.lognormal(mean=1, sigma=0.2, size=1000)
plt.hist(data, bins=50, density=True, alpha=0.6, color='g', label='Data')

s, loc, scale = lognorm.fit(data)
x = np.linspace(min(data), max(data), 1000)
lognormal_data = lognorm.pdf(x, s, loc=loc, scale=scale)

plt.plot(x, lognormal_data, 'r-', lw=2, label='Lognormal Distribution')
plt.xlabel('X-axis Label')
plt.ylabel('Y-axis Label')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Histogram Overlay with Lognormal Distribution')
plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: +one, but you should still use `floc=0` in the call of `lognorm.fit`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I guess OP can still use `floc=0` (thus implying `loc=0`) but wouldn't it fit better if we let scipy optimize all parameters? (just tried by adding an offset to `data` and it looks much better without `floc`)

Comment: Yes, it will fit better without `floc=0` (it has one more free parameter, after all), but the result is not the distribution that most people call *the* [log-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution).  If the location is not 0, the distribution is a shifted log-normal distribution.

Comment: Got it, thanks for clarifying!

Comment: This gave me the desired result, thank you!